# Daily data of same month over years

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have data from the same month over period of time and I trying to plot the mean by day of the motnh but I don´t know how to do it.
[This is how the dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtqE0.png)

The main code to get the dataframe:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime

inicio = date(1973, 1, 1)
#inicio = date(2019, 2, 15)
#final = date(2000, 10, 10)
final = date(1974, 3, 1)
delta = timedelta(days=1)
años=[]
links=[]
while inicio <= final:
    fechas=inicio.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    #años.append(datetime.strptime(fechas, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
    años.append(fechas)
    url='http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=samer&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR={}&MONTH={}&FROM={}12&TO={}12&STNM=80222'.format(fechas[0:4],fechas[5:7],fechas[8:10],fechas[8:10])
    links.append(url)
    inicio += delta


d = dict(zip(años, links))
df1=pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['Fecha', 'url'])
df1.set_index('Fecha', inplace=True)

Enero=pd.DataFrame()
Febrero=pd.DataFrame()

for i in df1.index:
    if i[5:7]=='01':
        Enero = Enero.append(df1.loc[i], ignore_index=False)
    elif i[5:7]=='02':
        Febrero = Febrero.append(df1.loc[i], ignore_index=False)

labels = ['PRES', 'HGHT', 'TEMP', 'DWPT', 'RELH', 'MIXR', 'DRCT', 'SKNT', 'THTA', 'THTE', 'THTV']

def reques(url):
    try:
        results = []
        peticion=requests.get(url)
        soup=bs(peticion.content, 'lxml')
        pre = (soup.select_one('pre')).text
        for line in pre.split('\n')[4:-1]:
            #print (line)
            if '--' not in line:
                row = [line[i:i+7].strip() for i in range(0, len(line), 7)]
                results.append(row)

            else:
                pass

        df5=pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=labels)
        #return x
        return df5

    except AttributeError:
        pass

SuperDF = pd.DataFrame()
SuperDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=labels)


startTime = datetime.now()
sin_datos=[]
for i in Febrero['url']:

    try:

        x=reques(i)
        df2=x
        y=str(df1[df1['url']==i].index.values)
        df2.index = [y] * len(x)
        SuperDF=SuperDF.append(x)


    except TypeError:
        sin_datos.append(df1[df1['url']==i].index.values)
        print (df1[df1['url']==i].index.values)



SuperDF.index= SuperDF.index.map(lambda x: x.lstrip("['").rstrip("]''"))
SuperDF.index = pd.to_datetime(SuperDF.index)
SuperDF=SuperDF.apply(pd.to_numeric)
SuperDF
```

I've been trying to do it whit this

```
import seaborn as sns


SuperDF = SuperDF[(SuperDF['TEMP']==0)]


ax = SuperDF.loc['02', 'RELH'].plot(marker='o', linestyle='-')
ax.set_ylabel('RELH');
```

but I got this error

```
KeyError: '02'
```

It works when i pass the year but i need the mean by day for the month. Any help will be appreciate.
[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ5Ix.png)

Comment: I have this error now: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Now I have this     <AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'eq'> and 
<TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable> if I drop 'eq'

Comment: use `df11.index.day == 2`

Comment: I have an array of true and false, but I want is a plot of the mean per day for the month two, dropping the years

Comment: It's hard to replicate your problem, since you haven't followed the [mcve] instructions on how to ask. But it seems like you need this: `df11.loc[df11.index.day == 2, 'RELH'].plot(marker='o', linestyle='-')`

Comment: I just edit the post

Comment: @LuisMedina how does reading from a database that only you have make the problem reproducible?

Comment: I just put the full code to make the problem reproducible.